# wget, curl HTTP addresses fail, HTTPS work, ping works

Tags: networking, wget, curl

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04.2, and I can't communicate with external http addresses anymore. I can `ping google.com`, I can `wget https://google.com`, but I can't `wget http://google.com`.

```
 $ wget http://google.com
     --2015-11-18 11:01:57--  http://google.com/
     Resolving google.com (google.com)... 74.125.224.99, 74.125.224.100, 74.125.224.98, ...
     Connecting to google.com (google.com)|74.125.224.99|:80... failed: Connection refused.
     Connecting to google.com (google.com)|74.125.224.100|:80...
```

A virtual machine on the same network running a fresher Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 does not have this problem, and can successfully wget http or https addresses.

This issue is causing `composer update` to error, with the following response from packagist:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "http://packagist.org/p/provider-[idstring].json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
```

There is no proxy for this network.

The only real difference I can figure between the two machines is that the one having the problem has a static IP, while the other uses DHCP.

I monitored the packets going through the network firewall from the two machines during a wget to google, and the firewall isn't blocking anything.

Thanks for reading.

**UPDATE**
I changed the static IP to another static and it worked. I was able to install traceroute while on the other IP and after changing back, ran it:

```
sudo traceroute -T -p 80 google.com
```

Gives me 30 rows of stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. We changed public IPs last week and I had a service object in the firewall with our old IP assigned, so presumably the traffic was going out fine and just not making it back. I updated the IP on the object to the new external and things started working again.